# Hosting a web service on a microcontroller

Tags: web-services, rest, microcontroller

I saw some devices online which had wifi and exposed some information which was collected by an samrt device (iOS in this case). Do you know of any microcontrollers which would be useful to expose some data read from a sensor (by WiFi)?

Example: Expose termometer web service - if someone request for the current temperature make the reading (or pass the cached reading) and send it to the requester.

Thx for your help in advance.

Comment: http://www.ezweblynx.com/product_info.php?cPath=Store&products_id=EZWEBLYNX_WIFI

Comment: I just saw this title and thought "how far we've come from ENIAC, from the 6502, from the IBM PC". Crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs) device [appears to be available for cheap](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=raspberrypi), has an Ethernet connection, and [even has a beta Stack Exchange community](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). You may be able to do something cheaper -- no GPU, for example -- but this might be a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently played with a http://ruggedcircuits.com/html/yellowjacket.html to do what you want to do.

Comment: Some detail on how to host a web service on a thing like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think Yoctopuce have some hardware that might allow you to do exactly that:

http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/an-autonomous-solar-weather-station

This is a solar weather station, based on a temperature sensor on a WiFi module. The WiFi module reads the temperature from the temperature sensor and automatically post it on the internet.  It's fully plug and play, no programming needed.